# How to write testcases for Zend framework 2 cookies?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have written the utility class which going to read and write cookies. I don't have an idea to write the test cases for my utility class.

How can i write test cases by using Zend framework 2 Http/Client?
Is this mandatory to test this utility class? (since it uses default zend framework methods)

```
class Utility
{
  public function read($request, $key){//code}

  public function write($reponse, $name, $value)
  {
   $path = '/';
   $expires = 100;
   $cookie = new SetCookie($name,$value, $expires, $path);
   $response->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
  }
}
```

--Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: if you rely on this piece of logic I would test this code. It is important to know that the cookie is always set with the given values when you call this method.

A way to look how you can test the piece is with an example from SlmLocale: a ZF2 locale detection module that writes possibly the locale down into a cookie. You can find the code [in the tests](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale/blob/ab075120b22d5ddbff03f533cbb817f8f7550871/tests/SlmLocaleTest/Strategy/CookieStrategyTest.php#L154-L160).

In your case:

```php
use My\App\Utility;
use Zend\Http\Response;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->utility  = new Utility;
    $this->response = new Response;
}
public function testCookieIsSet()
{
    $this->utility->write($this->response, 'foo', 'bar');

    $headers = $this->response->getHeaders();
    $this->assertTrue($headers->has('Set-Cookie'));
}

public function testCookieHeaderContainsName()
{
    $this->utility->write($this->response, 'foo', 'bar');

    $headers = $this->response->getHeaders();
    $cookie  = $headers->get('Set-Cookie');
    $this->assertEquals('foo', $cookie->getName());
}

public function testCookieHeaderContainsValue()
{
    $this->utility->write($this->response, 'foo', 'bar');

    $headers = $this->response->getHeaders();
    $cookie  = $headers->get('Set-Cookie');
    $this->assertEquals('bar', $cookie->getValue());
}

public function testUtilitySetsDefaultPath()
{
    $this->utility->write($this->response, 'foo', 'bar');

    $headers = $this->response->getHeaders();
    $cookie  = $headers->get('Set-Cookie');
    $this->assertEquals('/', $cookie->getPath());
}

public function testUtilitySetsDefaultExpires()
{
    $this->utility->write($this->response, 'foo', 'bar');

    $headers = $this->response->getHeaders();
    $cookie  = $headers->get('Set-Cookie');
    $this->assertEquals(100, $cookie->getExpires());
}
```

Comment: excellent solution! can you help me to write test case against `$this->utility->read($request, $key)`?

Comment: in the above code please use `$cookie  = $headers->get('Set-Cookie')[0];`   instead `$cookie  = $headers->get('Set-Cookie');`

Comment: You are right, you have to fetch its first value. For the other test, take a look at the link I provided. The method testLocaleInCookieIsReturned in that file is used to test reading cookie values.